# Frameset подгон по тексту

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли сделать так что бы `frameset1` подгонялся по тексту, то есть имеется страница с деревом в каждой папке этого дерева есть страница для открытия во `frameset2` но в первом `frameset` есть длинное название страниц, и по этому когда мы нажимаем + в дереве разворачивается папка и текста половину не видно приходится разделитель двигать руками вот мой код

`<FRAMESET bordercolor="#ffd800" cols="200,*" onResize="if (navigator.family == 'nn4') window.location.reload()"> 
     <frame src="Portal.html" name="treeframe">
     <frame src="Portal.html" name="basefrm">
</FRAMESET>`

подскажите как можно реализовать что бы `frameset` двигался в месте с нажатием + на дереве?